# How to htaccess requests from /folder/ to use /folder/ as root document

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, document-root

I'm currently writing a cms system in a subdirectory of the main html root and was wondering is possible using htaccess to redirect all requests that come from say /cms/ to use /cms/ as it's root directory.

e.g: example.com/cms/index.php calls the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/php/header.php"); ?>cu
```

and in return fetches:
   **example.com/cms/lib/js/jquery.js**
     **example.com/cms/lib/php/header.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cms%{REQUEST_URI} -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
```